# How do I store an integer input from the user into a variable in Tkinter?

Tags: variables, input, tkinter, integer

For my Python class were using `turtle` graphics.

We have too draw a target that appears at a random location on the screen. Got that.

Then a pop up window appears asking for what you think the coordinates of the target are. First the pop up box asks you to enter the `x` coordinate then it asks you to enter the `y` coordinate.

I'm having trouble saving the users inputed integers from my Tkinter window into variables I can use later in the program.

```
from Tkinter import *


window = Tk()                
window.title("Player Input") 
window.geometry('+350+130') 

thexinput = IntVar()  

L1 = Label(window, text="Enter the x coordinate for Mike")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1= Entry(window, textvariable= thexinput, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

def userinput():
    global inp
    a = raw_input(thexinput.get())
    inp = a

b = Button(window, text = 'Submit', command = userinput)
b.pack(side = BOTTOM)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `raw_input`, you just need to call the `get` method of the entry widget.

```
a = thexinput.get()
```